# What are hog futures?

Tags: meaning

Source: http://finance.yahoo.com/news/cramer-putin-windfall-103000769.html

> This Putin-hurts-chicken-farmers story is a classic example of how a huge positive gets turned by the press into something dastardly. Do you know that ever since Putin put this through, the price of all of our foodstuffs have been in virtual freefall? Do you know that **hog futures**, which had been soaring not that long ago, are now tumbling the maximum amount allowed and are back to where they were March 18? Do you know that the stubbornly high price of cattle is now crashing, as a newfound, Putin-inspired chicken glut has made poultry too competitive? Two weeks ago, we thought cattle could only go up in price. No more.

What does that mean? I don't understand.

Comment: I think this is General Reference. Googling ["hog futures"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22hog+futures%22&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB569GB569&oq=%22hog+futures%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.10243829j0j0&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) in quotes returns *thousands* of relevant instances, the vast majority of which make it quite clear what the term means. At the very least, they make it obvious you might need to Google further to find out exactly what ***futures*** are in a financial trading context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Futures are financial contracts giving the buyer an obligation to purchase an asset, and gives a seller an obligation to sell an asset. A full definition of it with examples can be found [here](http://www.investinganswers.com/financial-dictionary/optionsderivatives/futures-1002).

So in this context, it means that the futures for hogs were good before, but now are going down in value.

Answer (score 1):

'Futures' is a contraction of 'futures contract', which is essentially an agreement to pay today's price for a product delivered and paid for in the future. In this case, the product in question is hogs.

Futures trading is a form of investment. If you enter a futures contract for a product at a low price, which subsequently skyrockets, you can then sell the contract on without ever having received the product and still make a profit.

Wikipedia's article on futures can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_contract).

Answer (score 1):

*Hog futures* are contracts for future delivery of hog carcasses -- slaughtered pigs ready for processing into pork products.

Most agricultural and chemical commodities are traded nationally and internationally on commodity exchanges, where large-volume future contracts are traded. In the US, for instance, a standard hog contract is for 40,000 pounds, about 18 metric tons. Most such trades are not actually fulfilled but serve as a price-setting and -stabilizing mechanism for 'spot' or local trades in the physical commodities. 'Hog futures' is thus a measure of the average level of pork prices, which may be higher or lower in different locations depending on local costs and supplies.

As user8543 notes, the commodity exchanges are also frequented by speculators, who hope to make a profit from the changes in prices over time. The exchange thus permits a mutually valued interaction between speculators, who purchase the risk and opportunity in a future contract, and producers, who purchase commodities at predictable, stable prices.